# NFL 6th (consecutive) year captain patch

Tags: american-football, nfl

Since [2007](http://www.nfl.com/news/story/09000d5d80141cd7/article/nfl-clubs-to-recognize-team-captains), many NFL teams incorporated a "C" patch for team captains, and the number of gold stars filled in represents the number of consecutive years a player has been captain for his team<sub>[(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Football_League_team_captains)</sub>.

If he is a captain for his team for the 5th consecutive year, then the "C" on his patch is gold as shown below:

[image: "C" patch]

Drew Brees and Eli Manning are entering their 6th consecutive year as captains for their team. What will their "C" patch look like?

Comment: I've been wondering about this myself... and from everything that I've heard the patch will stay the same even for these players with more captain years than their captain patch can hold. In other forums, people have discussed changing the colors of the stars to denote more time as the captain.. not sure if this will happen or not though. Not necessarily an answer to your question, just what I've heard/found.

Comment: It would make sense to change the color of the stars. Honestly, I was surprised when the NFL gold plated the "C".

Comment: I search but came up empty, If I had to guess I will say it will stay like this, I guess we will have to see what happen..

Comment: That's what I figured @DorCohen. Guess this will be answered come September.

Comment: Pure speculation, but if you're a "5-star general" there's not much point in further recognition. The Wikipedia page basically says "any player who's been a captain for more than four years has a gold C", so my guess is it'll stay like this. They MIGHT be able to squeeze another star into line. Unfortunately the initial design uses white ~= silver as "empty" slots, so they can't make it work similar to the military "oak leaf cluster" and make one silver star equal five gold stars.

Comment: They could start "overlapping"; after making the C gold, you start embroidering the stars in black which will get you another 5 years until all the gold on the patch is now black, then you have to find another color or implement another system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"C" patches for players in their fifth year and sixth year as captain (and in subsequent years, I assume) are very similar, if not the same.

---

**Eli Manning in 2011**

- 5th year captain for the New York Giants
- Reebok was the NFL's apparel provider

[image: Eli Manning 2011]

**Eli Manning in 2012**

- 6th year captain for the New York Giants
- Nike is the NFL's jersey provider and New Era is the NFL's headwear provider

[image: Eli Manning 2012]