# Captain stars on NFL football jerseys

Tags: american-football, nfl, uniform

In American [NFL](http://www.nfl.com) football, team captains now wear a "C" on their jerseys.

Under the "C", there are stars.  Some players have white stars, while others have gold ones.  Others have a mix.

What is the significance of the stars?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From: [NFL 6th (consecutive) year captain patch](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/984/nfl-6th-consecutive-year-captain-patch?rq=1)

> the number of gold stars filled in represents the number of consecutive years a player has been captain for his team.

If each star is gold and the "C" is gold, then that player has been a captain for his team for 5 or more years<sub>[(1)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/1527)</sub>.

The white stars represent an empty placeholder for the gold stars. For example, if a player has two gold stars and two white stars, that represents that player has been a captain for that team for two years. See the table below:

```
White | Gold  | Meaning
-----------------------
0     | 4 + C | 5th year or more as captain for his team
0     | 4     | 4th year as captain for his team
1     | 3     | 3rd ...
2     | 2     | 2nd ...
3     | 1     | 1st ...
4     | 0     | represents 0 years of being a captain for his team*

* - I don't think this exists to wear.
```